# mongoexport E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: mongodb, export

The issue seems straight forward. I have a database (test) and a collection called (users) so I run the command:

```
mongoexport -d test -c users -o output.json
```

However I get the below error:

[image: E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier]

As per what I have figured out till now over the internet, this may have something to do with the file path but I am unsure as how to amend this as I never mess with PATH variable due to a bad experience...

Comment: You don't run `mongoexport` from the mongo shell, you have to run it from the OS shell (same as you run `mongo`)

Comment: Well aren't I a clown. Thank you very much! Please copy and paste as an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You don't run mongoexport from the mongo shell, you have to run it from the OS shell (same as you run mongo)

Comment: It's been over 3 years since you answered this question and I never thanked you. Thank you. :)

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Comment: @NiallLonergan it's been almost 3 years since you'd thanked me, and I've never responded.  You're welcome 

Answer (score 4):

mongoexport is not a Mongo shell command, it's an operating system command.

Just like you run mongo.exe to start the shell from OS prompt, you should run mongoexport the same way from OS prompt.   Example:

```
c:\mongodb\bin>mongoexport --db ventfeed --collection users --out C:\temp\contacts.json
```

Thanks