# uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :when trying to log into as an admin for mongo shell

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, backend, nodebb

I am following this tutorial

https://docs.nodebb.org/installing/os/windows/

I got thru most of it easily but when I go to login as an admin with this command:

```
mongo -u admin -p ojo --authenticationDatabase=admin
```

I get an error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:9
```

ojo is the password btw

the admin account was created and it shows up when you run show users

```
show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "userId" : UUID("e3c3df1d-f63d-48e3-ae65-b9cf03c86333"),
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "admin.admin2",
        "userId" : UUID("0b87390b-2c08-4e21-9183-8a2406a9304e"),
        "user" : "admin2",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Tried many attempts.

Comment: What is the complete output of the command?

Comment: > mongo -u admin -p ojo --authenticationDatabase=admin
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:9

Comment: @D.SM that is al

Comment: Take a look at [mongoexport E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431351/mongoexport-e-query-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier) - that error usually indicates you are already connected to the mongo shell.  That command should be run from the operating system command line.

Answer (score 2):

Don't open mongo shell and enter the connection string.

You have to enter the connection string (e.g., `mongo mongodb+srv://m999student:m999password@abc-xyz123.mongodb.net/testdb`) from the **operating system command prompt**

1. Press `win + r`
2. Type `cmd`
3. Paste the connection string
4. now you'll be prompted to enter password, enter it and that's all!